# Trouble Connecting to DB2 Database with R error 1114

Tags: r, db2

I've been trying to connect RStudio to a DB2 database and have been receiving the following error

```
rror: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: IM003: Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: 
A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. 
(IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1, C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\DB2CLIO.DLL).
```

I've been using this code

```
connection<-DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),Driver="IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1", 
Server = "NRDCWIP6",uid="nxxx",pwd="Wxxx")
```

which has been working well for a different database (SQL server). I'm working in Windows 10 and don't have a lot of information about the database itself since it's managed by an IT group that's quite busy. I'm still quite new to connecting R to databases as well. I do know that the platform for the DSN is 32-bit, but when I look under the User DSN tab, it is listed as 32/64 bit.

[image]

[image]

I know 1114 is a rather well known error, but I'm not sure where the problem is and I've tried numerous variations of this code. Anything will help!

Comment: Is your R-studio a 32-bit application, or is it 64-bit?  Use the *matching* bitness for the DSN, and delete and recreate that DSN with the *matching bitness* of odbcad32 ( 2 different versions exist, same file name, different directories of odbcad32.exe, one is 32bit other is 64-bit).

Comment: It's a 64-bit application. I went in and deleted it in the User DSN window (since I can't in the System DSN window) and tried to re-create it in the User DSN, but it still has the 32/64 bit. I'm not quite sure what to do.

Comment: Also, I should mention the other database is also 32bit and for some reason I haven't had any problems with that...

Comment: If your R-studio is 64-bit , then you should use the 64-bit odbcad32 (your question shows images of the 32-bit version of odbcad32). If a system-DSN already exists, create a differently named DSN with the 64-bit version of odbcad32.

Comment: When you use the 64-bit version of odbcad32, the driver-manager should load db2cli64.dll (not db2clio.dll which is the 32bit one). If the 64-bit driver is correctly registered (by Db2 client installation) with the microsoft odbc driver manager then db2cli64.dll would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here may be the answer for this situation:
**Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 1114**
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/specified-driver-could-not-be-loaded-due-system-error-1114

Here is the key note from above:

---

Resolving The Problem

Launch the odbcad32.exe from the Windows/SysWOW64/ folder and ensure that you have the current driver for the database version you are connecting to, specified in the Data Source that is being used in the map

---

Hope this helps.